# Why cant I set UIImage in UIimageview?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm trying to set an image from another ViewController using properties. But It doesn't work. Someone said that you only can change image from inside the Class. But i tried and its not working either way. Any ideas?

```
//viewcontroller1
    ViewController *viewcont = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:viewcont animated:NO completion:nil];
       [viewcont somemethodThatIscallemFromOutside];
//viewcontroller2

    -(void)somemethodThatIscallemFromOutside{
           if (!r12 && g12 && !b12) {
    green.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green"];
    self.Greenscore.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.readyplayer2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Greenready"];
}
    }
```

Comment: code please???? it is too less code to understand the problem

Comment: The line of code you put in your question is full of typos. Please post real code.

Comment: If you want to set Image from another ViewController then pass the image name and in ViewDidLoad() set the image.

Comment: Replace _ with : .... [myimageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"];

Comment: Post code of how you called somemethodThatIscallemFromOutside method:)

Comment: I think you are allocating the ViewController object again and again for this. You have to use one object to set the image

Comment: I think this because code posted is too less and there are so many possibilities for image is not reflecting on UI.

Comment: How many time ViewController object is allocated in your program??

Comment: Only once from what i know.

Comment: Try with moving [viewcont somemethodThatIscallemFromOutside]; line before presenting that view controller

Answer (score 0):

First of all no such method available

```
[UIImage imagename:@"Image1.png"]
```

Replace with

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"];
```

you should see also `myimageview` is intiliazed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myimageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Replace this with your code,your mistake in "_" which is be"="

```
[myimageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"]];
```

Comment: This is not valid syntax.

Comment: This should give error before compilation of code:)